# VirtualBox SDK - С++ проект под Visual Studio

Tags: c++, virtualbox

IDE - VisualStudio 2015, версия VB SDK - 5.1.6

Описание проблемы: захотелось написать небольшую тулзу - монитор для для отслеживания изменений на виртуальной машине. Решил писать на C++. Что подключено к проекту из Virtual Box SDK:

1. VirtualBox.h
2. VirtualBox.idl
3. VirtualBox_i.c

Во время сборки ругается на те типы/макроопределения, которые расположены в VirtualBox_i.c. Попробовал подключить библиотеку типов VirtualBox.tlb - однако, компилятор ругнулся, выдается сообщение, что данная библиотека уже задействована. Видимо, в каком-то из вышеперечисленных файлов она действительно подключается. Может я что-то упустил ? Что еще нужно подключить ?

UPD_0: сообщения об ошибках:

1. `unresolved external symbol _IID_IVirtualBoxClient`
2. `unresolved external symbol _CLSID_VirtualBoxClient`

[Код](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Main/testcase/tstVBoxAPIWin.cpp)

Comment: Как насчет [mcve] и конкретных сообщений об ошибках?

Comment: @alexolut, я полагаю, что те люди, которые делали сборку подобной конфигурации, понимают, о чем я говорю и сразу заметят, что я упустил (в плане импортирумых из VB SDK файлов). Но если Вам необходимы эти мессаги компилятора для того, чтобы помочь мне - то сейчас же обновлю вопрос.

Comment: А реализация "_IID_IVirtualBoxClient" в подключенных из SDK файлах есть?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, то, о чем мы говорим, получается в результате работы следующей макроподстановки: ```#define MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(type,name,l,w1,w2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) \
        const type name = {l,w1,w2,{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8}}``` Так что, вообще говоря, есть.

Comment: @isnullxbh ну тогда это неведомый подземный стук: реализация есть, а линкер не видит.

Comment: Найдите CLSID в том-же интернете или исходниках, и задайте вручную `CLSID _IID_IVirtualBoxClient =  {  .... }; ` возможно первую "_" в _IID_IVirtualBoxClient нужно убрать - и всё, она будет определена